# Migration of query from Oracle to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle

```
select 
    eue.PERSONID,
    eue.EID,
    eue.NAME_COMPLETE,  eue.
    eue.EMAIL_ADDRESS_OFFICE as EMAIL 
from  
    HAIL_ESS_USERS_EXTENDED_V eue
where 
    eue.PERSONID = p_person_id) eue
join 
   (select *
    from HAIL_ESS_ROLE_MAP
    where ROLE_ID in (select ID
                      from HAIL_ESS_ROLES
                      where upper(ROLE_NAME) like upper('Rewards and Recognition%'))) b on   eue.PERSONID = b.PERSON_ID(+);
```

Can anybody tell me the meaning of `(+)`? I have to migrate this query from Oracle to SQL Server
2008

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN it is in SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Equivalent is **LEFT OUTER JOIN**:

```
select eue.PERSONID,
           eue.EID,
           eue.NAME_COMPLETE,  eue.
           eue.EMAIL_ADDRESS_OFFICE as EMAIL 
    from  HAIL_ESS_USERS_EXTENDED_V eue
                 where eue.PERSONID = p_person_id) eue
         left outer join (select *
                from    HAIL_ESS_ROLE_MAP
                where   ROLE_ID in (select  ID
                                    from    HAIL_ESS_ROLES
                                    where   upper(ROLE_NAME) like upper('Rewards and Recognition%')))b
          on   eue.PERSONID=b.PERSON_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a notation for **LEFT OUTER JOIN**